# How to get all incoming request details in Spring REST service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http-post

I want to look at all request relative details (like headers, body) in my endpoint builded with Spring Boot. How to get it?

```
@RestController
public class SomeRestController {
    ...
    @PostMapping("path/")
    public String getResponse(@RequestBody SomeObject object) {
        // There I want to look at Request details... but how?
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Just add the `HttpServletRequest` as an argument and do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to get `RequestHeader` you can simply use `@RequestHeader` annotation in method

```
public String getResponse(@RequestBody SomeObject object,
 @RequestHeader("Content-type") String contentType) {
```

The other way you can do it is, this injection of `HttpServletRequest` will be taken care by spring

```
 public String getResponse(HttpServletRequest request, 
  @RequestBody SomeObject object) {
String userAgent = request.getHeader("content-Type");
}
```

or

```
  Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = (String) headerNames.nextElement();
        String value = request.getHeader(key);
```

Comment: what if header has some non-standard parts? So, what if I want to look at whole header part?

Comment: In third one we are getting complete headers and values

Answer (score 1):

> Define any controller method signature you need, possibly using one of the parameter annotations (such as @RequestParam, @RequestHeader, @PathVariable, and more) for a given scenario.

Reference: 
[15. Web MVC framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html)